# Second If statement gets called before first statement finished in one function

Tags: swift, function, if-statement, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have one function with 2 if statements inside it. Code:

```
func pictureFromFirebase(loginMethod: Int)
    {
    if loginMethod == 0 //FB
    {
        var profilePic = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/picture", parameters: ["height":300, "width":300, "redirect":false], httpMethod: "GET")
        let profilePicRef = storageRef.child((user?.uid)!+"/profile_pic.jpg")
        profilePicRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            } else {
               if (data != nil)
               {
                print("no need to download image from facebook")
                self.profileImage.image = UIImage (data: data!)
                }
            }
        }
        if profileImage.image == nil
        {
        print("downloading image from facebook")
        profilePic?.start(completionHandler: {(_ connection, _ result, _ error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil)
            {
                if let dictionary = result as? [String:Any], let data = dictionary["data"] as? [String:Any],
                    let urlPic = data["url"] as? String {
                    if let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: urlPic)! as URL)
                    {
                        let uploadTask = profilePicRef.put(imageData as Data, metadata: nil){
                         metadata, error in
                            if (error == nil)
                            {
                                let downloadUrl = metadata!.downloadURL
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                print("error in downloading image")
                            }
                        }
                        self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                    }
                }

            }
        })
    }
    }
    }
```

It gets only called when this function is triggered:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener() { (auth, user) in
            print("called")
            if let user = user {
                if(activeUser != user){
                let name = user.displayName
                self.profileName.text = name
                self.pictureFromFirebase(loginMethod: 0)
                }
            }
```

This is the normal output from the debug, when I already have set an image so downloading an image from Facebook is not needed:

-called
-downloading image from facebook
-called
-downloading image from facebook
-no need to download image from facebook
-no need to download image from Facebook

This is the output from the debug when I remove the whole second if statement (if profileImage.image == nil):

-called
-called
-no need to download image from facebook
-no need to download image from Facebook

From what I can see, apart that the function are called twice which is also wrong, the second statement gets called before the first statement is executed. Since the first statement takes a while before the profileImage is set, its nil when the second if statement is checking this value. How can I make sure this won't happen anymore? Thank you.

Comment: Please please please. Search before asking. This has been asked and answered a gazillion times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous methods!  You have to wait for the completion before you move on to the next step.

Put the second block within the first completion handler - like this

```
func pictureFromFirebase(loginMethod: Int)
{
    if loginMethod == 0 //FB
    {
        var profilePic = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/picture", parameters: ["height":300, "width":300, "redirect":false], httpMethod: "GET")
        let profilePicRef = storageRef.child((user?.uid)!+"/profile_pic.jpg")
        profilePicRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                // but we don't need to do anything yet.  Try to download the profile pic
            }
            if (data != nil)
            {
                print("no need to download image from facebook")
                self.profileImage.image = UIImage (data: data!)
            }
            else
            {
                // THIS IS THE BLOCK THAT HAS BEEN MOVED
                // WHICH WILL NOW BE EXECUTED IN TWO CONDITIONS - 
                // 1. AN ERROR IN THE DOWNLOAD
                // 2. NO PROFILE PIC AVAILABLE
                print("downloading image from facebook")
                profilePic?.start(completionHandler: {(_ connection, _ result, _ error) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil)
                    {
                        if let dictionary = result as? [String:Any], let data = dictionary["data"] as? [String:Any],
                            let urlPic = data["url"] as? String {
                            if let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: urlPic)! as URL)
                            {
                                let uploadTask = profilePicRef.put(imageData as Data, metadata: nil){
                                    metadata, error in
                                    if (error == nil)
                                    {
                                        let downloadUrl = metadata!.downloadURL
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        print("error in downloading image")
                                    }
                                }
                                self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                })
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I do this to an if statement? Can you provide me what I exactly need to add? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Russell! It worked when I had an image in the storage in firebase. But when I removed the profile picture to see if the function would automatically download the image from facebook again, it did nothing. It also didn't show the "downloading image from Facebook" print...

Comment: OK - If you have deleted the profile pic, then is the code going through the error check where you have `// Uh-oh, an error occurred!`?  If so, then you need to execute the code there

Comment: No, I don't get an error. I get nothing. I only see "called" as last debug output. The data however is nil. I added print(data) before "if (data == nil)" statement and it shows also no output. However when I re-add a profile picture I get an output of the number of bytes that downloaded image has. The problem is I think at "if (data == nil)". But the data is nil when there is no picture, how can this be...

Comment: You may still be getting an error - but you trap it without displaying anything.
I will update the code

Comment: Yea I now see it. the print(error) gives me that the profile picture does not exist... I fixed the problem by remove the "else{ if data == nil" by removing the "else" function. This way, an image would always downloaded never less an error is displayed. Anyway, it works now but its a bit sloppy. If an error is presented, it will show up in my debug session and continues to download an image. You think this is good enough?

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer - I think the flow there is reasonable - and should trap all eventualities

Comment: You should earn a medal. Thank you very much for your time! Now I can continue :3